# How do I sort this multiple queried result table in PHP using a drop down?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, sorting

I got a code which generate a table like this

[image: table]

and the code is here

```
$num1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mtable WHERE DataVersionDate='$datav' && Pathogen='$pathogen' && Topic='$topic1' && Indicator='$ind1' && IndicatorSubGroup='$subindg1' && (Country IN ('$sql_cntys') OR  WHORegionAC IN ('$sql_cntys')) ");
$num2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mtable WHERE DataVersionDate='$datav' && Pathogen='$pathogen' && Topic='$topic2' && Indicator='$ind2' && IndicatorSubGroup='$subindg2' && (Country IN ('$sql_cntys') OR  WHORegionAC IN ('$sql_cntys')) ");
$num3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mtable WHERE DataVersionDate='$datav' && Pathogen='$pathogen' && Topic='$topic3' && Indicator='$ind3' && IndicatorSubGroup='$subindg3' && (Country IN ('$sql_cntys') OR  WHORegionAC IN ('$sql_cntys')) ");
$num4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mtable WHERE DataVersionDate='$datav' && Pathogen='$pathogen' && Topic='$topic4' && Indicator='$ind4' && IndicatorSubGroup='$subindg4' && (Country IN ('$sql_cntys') OR  WHORegionAC IN ('$sql_cntys')) ");
$num5 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mtable WHERE DataVersionDate='$datav' && Pathogen='$pathogen' && Topic='$topic5' && Indicator='$ind5' && IndicatorSubGroup='$subindg5' && (Country IN ('$sql_cntys') OR  WHORegionAC IN ('$sql_cntys')) ");

$data = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($num1))
{
    $c = $row['Country'];
    if (!isset($data[$c]))
    {
        $data[$c] = array('Country' => $c);
    }
    $data[$c]['MidEstimate1'] = $row['MidEstimate'];
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($num2))
{
    $c = $row['Country'];
    if (!isset($data[$c]))
    {
        $data[$c] = array('Country' => $c);
    }
    $data[$c]['MidEstimate2'] = $row['MidEstimate'];
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($num3))
{
    $c = $row['Country'];
    if (!isset($data[$c]))
    {
        $data[$c] = array('Country' => $c);
    }
    $data[$c]['MidEstimate3'] = $row['MidEstimate'];
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($num4))
{
    $c = $row['Country'];
    if (!isset($data[$c]))
    {
        $data[$c] = array('Country' => $c);
    }
    $data[$c]['MidEstimate4'] = $row['MidEstimate'];
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($num5))
{
    $c = $row['Country'];
    if (!isset($data[$c]))
    {
        $data[$c] = array('Country' => $c);
    }
    $data[$c]['MidEstimate5'] = $row['MidEstimate'];
}
$i = 0;
echo "<table width='880' align='center'>";
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    echo ($i % 5) ? "<tr>" : "<tr>" ;
    echo "<td style='padding-left:10px' width='280'>" . $row['Country']."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' width='120'>" . $row['MidEstimate1']."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' width='120'>" . $row['MidEstimate2']."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' width='120'>" . $row['MidEstimate3']."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' width='120'>" . $row['MidEstimate4']."</td>";
    echo "<td align='center' width='120'>" . $row['MidEstimate5']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>" ;
}

echo "</table>" ;
```

How can I sort this table column wise ? that is using a drop down list with values "Country", "Indicator 1", "Indicator 2", "Indicator 3", "Indicator 4", "Indicator 5". when a user select values table must list values with respective sorted column. Please help.

**I got the answer from here** [Sort Multi Array](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/sortarray/)

Comment: Are you committed to using SELECT boxes for the sorting? If not take a look at jQuery DataTables plugin http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: yest I want to use a select box ? any help ?

Comment: See if this will do anything like what you want: http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

Comment: thanx but my table is a result of multiple queries how do I sort that ? also I want it by a selection of dropdown list. I managed with some ajax code to open a sortby.php page and tried wwith sql sorting using if condition but its not giving the right output. ??

Comment: **I got the answer from here [link]http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/sortarray/[link], hope it might useful to all ... thanx for the help**

Comment: OK I suggest you answer your own question with that link and then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?PHP 
function orderBy($data, $field) { 
$code = "return strnatcmp(\$a['$field'], \$b['$field']);"; 
usort($data, create_function('$a,$b', $code)); 
return $data; } 

$data = orderBy($data, 'age'); 
?>
```

The complete reference of the code is available from [here](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/sortarray/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should gather all queries to one. Something like `SELECT * FROM matble WHERE ....`.

And then iterate over result and create output depending on your requirements.

Comment: I did not understand what you suggest, could u give me a hint/sample ?